# Angular 2 Material not resizing or adjusting for mobile/smaller width

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 2 Material to have a basic navbar setup here:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z2">
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="openSideNav()">
     <mat-icon class="md-24" >menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span>{{this.title}}</span>
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="infoMenu">Information</button>
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="toolsMenu">Tools</button>
  <button mat-button>Blog</button>
  <span class="fill-space"></span>
  <!-- Pull right -->
  <div class="float-right">
    <button mat-icon-button>
      <li class="fa fa-user-circle fa-2x"></li>
    </button>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

When angular.io site is resized (for mobile, or small package on desktop) it adjusts fine as seen here:

[image]

But when mine is re-arranged the buttons simply get pushed out of screen view:
[image]

I was under the assumption that using just the material items the page would act responsive automatically, much like using bootstrap elements.
Or do I need to create code to do a similar thing as seen on angular.io (I.E. check width of page and adjust when its out of room) and if I do have to create the code is there are streamline way do check if items in a toolbar dont fit the screen? thanks

Comment: generally no - you need to design your complete site in responsive techniques in order for it to adjust to different devices/widths

Comment: This plunker is made with you snippet and is responsive: https://plnkr.co/edit/Mp2fDFQrWBOimTZlaika?p=preview. Did you make changes to your code?

Comment: @faboolous is tehre any tutorials on this, is it just using CSS to detect width and adjusting? do I use typescript/javascript to get the width and adjust?

Comment: @Vega that isnt responsive tho? the buttons get hidden as you move the bar in, I want the buttons to adjust or fall into a dropdown as that happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I totally forgot about 'flex-layout' which will just do all of this automatically as long as I place the correct calls to functions.

Here is a runthrough of a responsive navbar with flex and angular materials: https://dev-plaza.com/responsive-navbar-mit-angular-flex-layout-und-angular-material

and here is flex-layout: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

and here finally is flexbox documentation: http://cssreference.io/flexbox/

Comment: Also note that I am using bootstrap scss to resize my text values!